# Firebase track the time a user is logged in?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

In Firebase is there a way I can track the time a user is logged in?. I'm creating a student management app and I need to track the time a student is logged in, in order to mark them present. For example if a class is from 10:30 to 11:30 the student needs to be logged in for at least 50 minutes in order to mark them as present.

Comment: Don't waste energy in such useless feature. Lazy students will always find a way.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a document containing the server timestamp in Firestore after the user has logged in:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    const user = userCredential.user;
    firebase.firestore().collection("logins").add({
      userId: user.uid,
      timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    }).then(() => {
      console.log("Logged In")
    })
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
  });
```

You can add the following security rule to make sure the incoming timestamp is Firestore's server timestamp.

```
allow create: if request.resource.data.timestamp == request.time;
```

Alternatively, you can use the [lastSignInTime](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.UserMetadata#optional-lastsignintime) property in user metadata.

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.metadata.lastSignInTime
```